# Handling timezones for Javascript date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple timer countdown HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<title>Countdown</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import "http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.countdown.css";

#defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date("December 9, 2011 11:30:00");
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    $('#year').text(2011);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Countdown</h2>
<p>Counting down to 11:30am Dec 9th, <span id="year">2011</span>.</p>
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is that it doesn't handle timezones properly. For example, it shows the correct countdown in my timezone but if someone views it from say in CST, it's off by 2 hours. What's the proper way to set the `Date` in the Javascript code? Right now, I have this

```
    austDay = new Date("December 9, 2011 11:30:00");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this will interact with the countdown plugin...

```
austDay = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));
```

Comment: This should work but it doesn't and I'm not sure why. First off, specifying 12 for the month of Dec in UTC put the actual date out in Jan?

Comment: Month is zero-indexed. Everything else should be normal. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp

Comment: Dudh, I never noticed that, thanks for the tip. It still didn't work though, there's a still the 2 hour difference from CST.

Comment: Is the date your are counting down to in a specific timezone? I'm viewing this in CST and it's calculating correctly: at 2011-11-30 12:06 CST > 8 days 23 hours 23 minutes 40 seconds

Comment: Also, you should note that this is relying on the user's time. If their computer doesn't have the correct time set then the countdown will be off.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
var tz = d.getTimezoneOffset();
var date = new Date("December 9, 2011 11:30:00");
austDay = date.setMinutes( date.getMinutes() + tz );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work with the plugin